# Chart.js: "stacked" not working with scatter line charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to display stacked lines with the chart.js type 'scatter'. Unfortunately, the option "stacked: true" seems not to work here.

Please check the following example (or this [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/faq9tk1j/4/)).

```js
var ctx = $('#myChart');

var chart = new Chart (ctx,{
 type:  'scatter',
   data: {
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Line 1',
        fillColor: 'rgb(200,200,200)',
        strokeColor: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
        data: [{
          x: 2020,
          y: 20000
        },{
          x: 2030,
          y: 30000
        },{
          x: 2040,
          y: 40000
        }]
      },{
        label: 'Linie 2',
        fillColor: 'rgb(200,200,200)',
        strokeColor: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
        data: [{
          x: 2020,
          y: 5000
        },{
          x: 2030,
          y: 10000
        },{
          x: 2040,
          y: 15000
        }]
      }]
    }, 
  options: {
    elements: {
      line: {
        tension: 0.000001
      }
    },
    showLines: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Chart.js Documentation [says](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html) "The scatter chart supports all of the same properties as the line chart." and for line charts, there is a "stacked" option (see [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html?h=stacked)). In addition, this [issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/2867) reported on GitHub also seems to prove, that there is a "stacked" option for scatter charts.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same issue,have u found the way around it?